# Shell how to use a command to every regular file in and below the Dir

Tags: bash, unix, shell

So what I have to do is find all regular files within and below the directory.
For each of these regular files, I have to egrep for pattern($ARG) and find out if the output of the file matches the pattern ($ARG), if it does it will add one to the counter.

What I have so far is the file command:

```
$count = 0
file *
```

However, I am having trouble getting egrep &ARG > /dev/null/ ; echo $? to run through each file that appears from (file *).

I understand that file * | egrep directory > /dev/null ; echo $? will output 0 because it find the pattern 'directory' in the file, but am having trouble getting it to loop through each regular file so I can add one to the counter every time the pattern is matched.

Comment: If you just want to count the files which contain the pattern, the following will show it: `find -type f -print0|xargs -0 egrep -l ...|wc -l`, where `...` is the parameter list you want to pass to `egrep`. This finds all standard files in the current directory and below, and this list is built into a file list for `egrep -l`, which shows the name of any file containing the match pattern, and the number of files is counted by `wc -l`.

Comment: Your question is very confusing, would you mind rewording it? What do you intend to achieve with `file *`? `file` returns the type of file(s) specified in its arguments. What do you intend with this? as @AFH states above, the best tool for obtaining all files within a directory is `find`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want.  Essentially, it creates a list of all the files in the directory and below; then scans them, printing the file name of any hits; then it counts how many file names are returned.

```
count=$(egrep -l "$ARG" $(find . -type f) | wc -l)
```

It is possible that the find will return too many files (you will get the error, "Argument list too long").  In which case, this slower, but surer mechanism will work:

```
count=$(find . -type f -exec egrep -l "$ARG" {} \; | wc -l)
```